# Conjugating words when localizing an application

Tags: localization, standards, conventions

When translating an application into Spanish (and consequently many other languages), what is tense and conjugation should used for buttons that are verbs? (ex. "Submit", "Save", etc.)

I've converted my phone into Spanish to see what other apps do. It seems like some are using the infinitive of the verb, while others are conjugating it to the third person present tense.

I would think that using the third person present tense is the best way to go. I think that's what's done in English. However, I'm no grammar wiz, so I don't know if that's true or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't speak Spanish. Your approach can be correct. I would recommend you check MS style guides which are in English and available online. 
[Microsoft Style Guide Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/Language/StyleGuides)

However, I wanted to attract your attention to a point about UI labels.

In the buttons such as `Submit`, `Save`, `Cancel`, most of the time they are translated as imperative since you give command to the device in these buttons (you ask device to "send", "cancel". On the other hand, when the device asks you to do something, in some languages, imperative is seen as offensive like Turkish. So you have use polite form of imperative. Maybe it makes difference in your case (such as usted vs ustedes)
I hope my answer helps you.